# Realtime voice processing in discord?

Tags: discord, voice-recording

Gday Guys,

me and my friends want to play Bingo with another friend of us. Basicaly every time we play together he will rage and say some hilarious stuff. 
The initial plan was to write the words down in a 3x3 grid. And when he had said sth. you wrote down, you can cross it. You win if you have crossed all words diagonally, vertically or horicontically.

But I as a programmer do not want to use pen and paper (its boring). So why not write a game or so?

So I wonder, is there any known API to listen to the discord audio channels? There are some bots you can use to record the audio for [podcasts](https://craig.chat/home/). How do they access the audio? Do you guys have any idea to deal with that?

Comment: You will have to ask the author. He's also on GitHub. https://github.com/Yahweasel `ennuicastr` and `ennuizel` are important pieces in his `craig` project. In general there are very few discord bots that manipulate audio from other users due to the complexity. All the projects I have seen so far haven't standardized a way and it is highly customized to their needs and also very hacky (not sure about his project). Your question is too broad and too advanced for StackOverflow.

Comment: Why bother with Discord at all. Create a VM, run linux, install discord, setup audio-loopback, profit.

Comment: Oh turns out Windows has an audio-loopback called Stereo-Mix